# Universal Apps template missing in Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10

I still cannot create a new Universal App in Visual Studio 2015 Community I have installed.

I thought the reason was I was running Windows 8.1. Today I upgraded to Windows 10, but there is no "Universal Apps" templates available.

I have installed Windows 10 SDK but nothing changed.

How can I fix that?

Thank you.

Comment: The final Windows 10 SDK for Visual Studio 2015 (as of writing this) isn't yet available once it is, you'll be able to install then use these templates

Answer (score 12):

You need to install the [Windows 10 Developer Tools](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/F/C/6FC19DBF-C223-41D0-835A-BD2155BC950D/VSToolsForWindows1C.exe) (select modify and select the Win10 tools + Emulator if wanted). After this you see the template in New Project.

Comment: Thanks.  One would think it would be installed by default.

Comment: @KrisKrause Microsoft released the Win10 VS tools 1 week after the release of the VS2015 RTM. That's why it is not part of VS2015RTM.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I don't see windows 10 mobile template in visual studio, I do have universal app template though, What should I do?

Comment: @thewarri0r9 post a picture of your setup

Comment: @magicandre1981 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/gMx3nBP.png?1" width="100" height="100">

Comment: @thewarri0r9 sorry, I mean from the VS 2015 setup

Comment: @thewarri0r9 this is strange. Do you use the RTM or the Update1 version of VS2015?

Comment: @magicandre1981 In this screen shot, it shows update 1 of VB15: http://i.imgur.com/ht6n3KR.png?1

Comment: @thewarri0r9 I have no idea. Ask this in the MSDN forums: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=vssetup

Answer (score 3):

As of March 2016, the VS development tools including the ones for cross platform development with `Xamarin`, tools are embedded in the `Visual studio 2015 update 2`, both community and enterprise versions.

All you need to do is go to the ISO file and try to re-install from the ISO file then select modify from the options then select universal windows development tools. Refer to the screenshots for better understanding.

[image: select modify and choose UWP Dev tools] 
[image: for cross platform dev tools with xamarin, android emulator too, etc]

Comment: This is what worked for me. I never installed the UWP development tools when I installed VS2015. Thanks for the screenshots too!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @magicandre1981, the Universal App template appears only if Windows 10 developer tools are selected while running the installer and choosing the custom setup. Also, there is no such thing as a separate template for mobile or desktop as this is what is the true meaning of universal.
You can simply choose the Universal App template and write code to target any/all of the [device families](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn706137.aspx) as explained in [Guide to Universal Windows Platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide). 

Further, add reference to extension SDK specific to device-family ( Windows Mobile Extensions for mobile api).

To use device specific api, you must first check its availability.

```
  Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons");
```