# Can SAPI voices be used with the Microsoft Speech API?

Tags: windows, text-to-speech, sapi

I currently have several custom SAPI voices that work in SAPI-compliant applications. However, applications such as Microsoft Powerpoint use the Microsoft Speech API and the SAPI voices are not available.

Is there any way to allow Microsoft Speech API-based applications to use existing SAPI voices?

Comment: Microsoft has several speech APIs.  Can you be a bit clearer about *which* Microsoft speech API you're referring to?

Comment: @EricBrown This will give some context. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40406719/windows-10-tts-voices-not-showing-up/40427509#40427509

Comment: So you're trying to use SAPI voices with the WinRT Speech Synthesis APIs?

Comment: Correct. Right now the Speech API voice list only shows the three MS voices vs over 50 voices in my SAPI voice list.

Answer (score 0):

Officially, no.   There's a completely unsupported and unreliable hack that might work (or it might not, depending on the machine and the voice in question).   It also might cause security issues as well (since you're loading 3rd party code into your target applications).  It also requires you to hand-edit the registry.

Anyway, if you *really* want to try this **COMPLETELY UNSUPPORTED HACK**, start editing the registry, and export the keys under

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\`

to a text file.   Export each subkey under `Tokens` to a different text file, and skip any voices from Microsoft (where `Attributes\Vendor` will have a value of 'Microsoft').   You might also need to export the keys in

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\`

as well (export to a different file).

Then, open up the text file, and search & replace `Microsoft\Speech` with `Microsoft\Speech_OneCore`.   Save the file, and then import the edited file into the registry.

Reboot, and you should have the new voices.